# What is the technical difference between the shown time statements

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

```
$time1 = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", time()));
$time2 = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", time()));
$time1 = $time1 + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
$time2 = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $time2) . " +1 week");
```

The second line and third line obviously doing different things in my code. That is when i am processing a date which is older than a month. Is it supposed to be like that ? And why is it doing that ?

Comment: Seems odd that you are converting timestamps to strings to convert to timestamps again (first two lines).

Comment: Actually the first 2 lines is not wat i have in my code. Replace the first 2 lines with the date valued i get from database. So ignore those lines if its odd :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that

```
$time1 = $time1 + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
```

adds 7 × 24 hours, whereas

```
$time2 = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $time2) . " +1 week");
```

adds one week.

Normally, of course, those are the same thing, but your profile says that you live in New Zealand, and Wikipedia says that New Zealand switches from daylight-saving-time to regular time on the first Sunday in April, which was yesterday (or, er, two days ago for you). So it may recently have been the case for you that one week was actually 7 × 24 + 1 hours (because the hour from 2:00 to 3:00 AM on April 1st happened twice), instead of 7 × 24 hours.

Similarly, in the spring you'll find that one week can be 7 × 24 − 1 hours.

Comment: OOOOH I see wat you mean!! May be thats why my operations are not happening as it should be on the right time!! Thanks for that..

Comment: So i should be using +1 week type instead of algebra!!

Answer (score 1):

They should be doing calculating the same thing, however line 3 is doing simple algebra to calculate the integer value. Line 4 has to parse the date, and the `+1 week` string and generate the same value.

Using strtotime will be slightly slower due to a function call + parsing the string value and converting it into the correct unix timestamp.

Comment: So you mean to day there will not be any difference by value for those 2 lines ??